# These United States

Tags: meaning

On the web site of [NBC](https://www.nbcmiami.com/entertainment/entertainment-news/SNL-Summer-Hillary-Clinton-Jeb-Bush-2016-President-304031391.html) you can read (my emphasis):

> "May I have just a moment of your summer? I'm Hillary Clinton 
>   and I'm running for president of **these United States**," said 
>   Clinton, clawing at the air, her hands like pincers.

I heard the same expression in this [Saturday Night Live](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNa8I50XJgQ) episode (between 00:15 and 00:16).

What's the purpose of saying "**these** United States"? Is it supposed to convey some meaning? Does it have a humorous connotation?

There is only one country with this name, therefore "these" does not make sense to me. If there were several entities with the same or similar name (such as Upper Austria and Lower Austria), that would make sense (this Austria, not the other one).

Comment: It's a play on the original literal plural meaning of States that are United. "I'm vacationing in The Bahamas this year." "Which one?"

Comment: 'This Earth, this Realm, this England'. Identification / avoidance of the impersonal / hinting at greatness.

Comment: It's similar to the collective noun used for sports teams. Even though they are single team names, the names refer to multiple players on the teams. Personally, I would say ***the*** *United States* (referring to the single country), but ***these*** *United States* is far preferable to ***this*** *United States* . . . (Also personally, if I did use ***these***, I would use the generic form for the group of states rather than the proper name of the country: ***these*** *united states*.)

Comment: Also note that actual speech doesn't have punctuation or capitalization. Transcripts of the speech are simply making assumptions. (Although, perhaps, it's the actual text that's been read that has been copied.)

Comment: (For a country that takes a singular form, I'd drop the article altogether. *Justin Trudeau is the prime minister of Canada*, not of *the Canada* or *this Canada*. This may be logically inconsistent, but it's a matter of what "sounds" right.)

Comment: Other countries with a similar form of name (united/union + plural) include the UAE and historically the USSR. Russian doesn't use articles and arabic uses them a lot so it is hard to make a connection. Using "these" is a way of placing greater emphasis on the states.

Comment: Surely, as @EdwinAshworth suggests, Hillary is being folksy/ingratiating/manipulative/political.  "May I have just a moment of your summer" (my friends ('Romans, countrymen'!), my fellow citizens).  "I'm running for president of these United States" (of *ours*, she might also have added).  Hillary was, conspicuously NOT talking down to ordinary people.  She is making herself one among many.

Comment: Technically, the USA is not the only United States. Another example is Estados Unidos Mexicanos, and there are probably others.

Comment: @Dan Hey, I like visiting the States. I'd like to be able to continue to do so. I was diplomatic in my choice of words. I left some out.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'm surprised so many reactions to this question are so po-faced, seeing no connection between Hillary's informal usage and how she might have been hoping this would further her political ambitions.

Comment: @Dan 'Mentioning no connection' and 'seeing no possible connection' are far from equivalent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - agreed.  In the context of the OP, however, it is a surprising connection not to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of **these** emphasises the plural, the United States consists of multiple states (e.g. California, Texas, etc.). It case of SNL, it's likely for comic effect to say **these united** in a time when there is division (on different levels) between those states.

It may also be more serious, as [noted on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-say-these-United-States-while-others-say-the-United-States), to emphasise that the individual states have some autonomy and some things that may be inferred from that, for example (some) immunity to corruption (as noted by the Quora answer).

Another word play is to refer to the US as **divided Stated of America**, as [some do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_States_of_America) to emphasise the divisions.

It's also interesting to not that it's not really a recent thing. [This painting of Abraham Lincoln, dated 1864](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/2008680376/), is titled:

> *The people of **these United States** are the rightful masters of both congresses and courts, not to over-throw the Constitution, but to over-throw the men who pervert that Constitution*

Comment: An earlier almost-reference exists in the Declaration of Independence. While the passage refers to _the Representatives of the united States of America_, it also declares _That these united Colonies are, and of Right ought to be Free and Independent States_.